# getChildHtml inside a foreach with a block name

Tags: magento-1.9, category, layout, full-page-cache, phtml

I have content inside list.phtml which shows the stock count of each product on the category page. this shows if an Admin is logged in.

The problem I have is that Lesti FPC (Full Page Cache) caches it and then everyone can see it.

I have created a custom block and moved my code into the new PHTML file with block name 'colors' and used this to display it `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('colors') ?>`

Unfortunately as this is inside a foreach loop it shows the stock count as 0.

How can I get the getChildHtml to show the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in Lesti FPC that will allow you to have separate cache files based on Custom Group.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add your block in list of dynamic block. Look in 
https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc/blob/master/app/code/community/Lesti/Fpc/etc/config.xml  for more info.

Hope it helps you.